# How to calculate the creepage distance of a package through package outline?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, inverter, semiconductors, packages

How do I calculate the creepage distance of a package which is not specified by the manufacturer?

By looking at the drawing of the package, could I calculate it? If yes then how?

[image]

Comment: No, you can't calculate it based on external dimensions.

Comment: @Andyaka Could you please let me know which information I need to have in order to calculate that?

Comment: You need information from the manufacturer and, if safety is involved you need that component approved.

Comment: Addition and subtraction?

Comment: @winny Could you please Elaborate? addition and subtraction of which dimensions?

Comment: Of those that forms your shortest creepage across the device.